# Convert date to specific format

Tags: java, android

Convert this date format **2013-01-15 06:20:00** to this format **2013-01-15**. Just Simply remove Time from date. I used

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(
                    "yyyy-mm-dd");
            //Date convertedDate = new Date();
            Date convertedDate = null;
            try {
                 convertedDate = dateFormat.parse(dateString);
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

how to get or remove time from date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to parse it only for display purpose, You can use this one :

```
String input = "2013-01-15 06:20:00";
System.out.println(input.split(" ")[0]);
```

Comment: good answer and efficient also. just two lines. Great.

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class DateFormatting {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        String input = "2013-01-15 06:20:00";
        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        Date theDate = dateFormat.parse(input);
        String output = dateFormat.format(theDate);
        System.out.println(output); // prints 2013-01-15
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this format:

> SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd")

And then parse a new Date ala:

> String s = dateFormat.format(new Date())

Comment: i used this format also but its generating like this:Sun Jul 06 00:00:00 IST 1975

Comment: Well the date will still have a time component, you cannot get rid of it. The format just determines how the output looks like, since this is usually what matters in these cases. If you get the above output, you are not using the format I mentioned.

Comment: So any other solution for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just use

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
            Date convertedDate = null;
            try {
                 convertedDate = dateFormat.parse(dateString);
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

use

```
DateFormat df = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.MEDIUM , Locale.ENGLISH);
```

output
Feb 20,1991

Comment: This emits the wrong date format. Try again.